# Python3 Man in the Middle: Bind socket to ANY IP

Tags: python, sockets, networking, mitmproxy, man-in-the-middle

I am trying to build a simple Man-in-the-Middle Tool, similar (but much simpler) to mitmproxy. To get into a MITM position i am using arpspoof. The following picture shows a simplified setup. (I am using UDP sockets for the connection, because Client and Server utilizs a specific protocol (DTLS) and the library i am using to setup the connection wraps UDP sockets.)

[image: Simple Tool Setup, Conecept]

While all my other test without actual arp spoofing went well, i hit a wall with this setup, since i am (understandybly) not able to bind my tool on 192.168.0.3:12345 to 192.168.0.1:12345 and the incoming datagrams from Client (that are correctly showing up on 192.168.0.3) are addressed to 192.168.0.1.
The resoluting questions are:

- Is there a way to bind a socket to an IP that is NOT assigned to an interface on the machine (with python 3)?
- Is there another option i am missing? (I need to use the DTLS library, doing everything manually with the limited DTLS support of scapy probably won't work out)
- If i can somehow overcome this, how would i achieve spoofing the outgoing Datagrams on an existing socket?
- Is there maybe another option to proxy the incoming traffic, modify the destination adress, forward it to my tool, craft the response, proxy it, modify the source adress and send it to the client? (If this does make any sense to you)

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt search for `ip_nonlocal_bind` (assuming your on Linux).

I've done something similar with raw sockets, but it requires you to craft you own protocol headers

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. i played around with this setup and i am able to bind to the desired ip:port, but the incoming datagrams never actually reach the socket. I tried to break the problem down further and did a simple UDP script to receive connections with nc. While I am able to receive the data when i send datagrams with nc to the actual ip address (192.160.0.3:1337), i am not able to receive data when i bind to 192.168.0.3:1337 (the arp spoofed address), despite seeing the incoming datagrams in wireshark. (arp spoofing is working)

Comment: You will have to put the interface in promiscuous mode.

Comment: Thanks again, i did some further testing today. I am enabling promiscous mode with `sudo ip link set ens33 promisc on` and can check the status with `ifconfig ens33` where the flag for promiscous mode is visible. I then setup the socket: `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)` and bind it to the interface `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str("ens33" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))` and bind it to the nonlocal IP `s.bind(("192.168.0.1",1337))` followed by a simple recfrom. I do not receive anything on the socket. (incoming traffic is visible in Wireshark)